# Should velocity be taken into account when an object is tracted at constant velocity? (Incline problem)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question

[image]

Suppose an object of mass $M$  is tracted in the down-up direction  without friction on an incline ( with a tilt of  $\alpha$ degrees).

Velocity $V$ is given and is said to be constant.

The question is : what is the tension $T$ in the cable that pulls the object?

I would say that since velocity is constant , there is no acceleration and therefore the resultant force is $\vec{0}$ ( by $f = m.a$).

So we should have apparently  $[(Mg)sin(90-\alpha)] +T = 0$ and $T= - (Mg)sin(90-\alpha)$.

***But I came acroos many exercices of the same type , each time givng a different velocity.
This makes me think that the value of velocity should be taken into account.***

Is there somethng wrong in my approach?

Comment: Review the force due to gravity on an inclined plane and the relationship between sine and cosine. Your observation that constant velocity implies tension equal to the relevant component of the gravitational force and that the value of the velocity is irrelevant are correct, but your formula is a bit off.

Comment: Velocity would matter if friction was nonzero of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a constant speed up the incline, The external force 'F ' must balance the component of the gravitational force  which acts down the incline.